# ExtJS Error "TypeError: Ext.state is undefined"

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am new to ExtJS. I saw an example and copied that on an empty page. When I run this page I get an error:
**TypeError: Ext.state is undefined
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));**
Here is the complete code of what I am trying:
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ExtJS CRUD</title>
    <link href="extjs/resources/ext-theme-neptune/ext-theme-neptune-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));

        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose',
            store: [[1, "Harpo"], [2, "Chico"], [3, "Groucho"]],
            displayField: 'name',
            typeAhead: true,
            forceSelection: true,
            valueField: 'abbr',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            stateful: true,
            stateId: 'myIdentifierUniqueAmongAllMyStatefulComponentsUsedToStoreAndFetchMyState',

            stateEvents: ['select'],

            getState: function (me) {
                // On any of the stateEvents, the framework runs this.
                // "Hey component, what do you want me to remember for you?
                return {
                    value: this.getValue()
                };
            },
            applyState: function (state) {
                // On component initialization, the framework runs this.
                // "Hey component, here's that object I saved for you
                this.setValue(state.value);
            }

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to require it:

`Ext.require('Ext.state.*');`

Comment: I replaced Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));
 with Ext.require('Ext.state.*'); Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider')); but it has no effect.